# regex $1 variable reset

Tags: regex, perl

I have following sample perl script:

```pl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $cont1 = 'item:test';
my $cont2 = 'item:test';

$cont1 =~ s/item:(.*)/$1/; my $one = $1;
$cont2 =~ s/dtms:(.*)/$1/; my $two = $1;

print "one = $one\ntwo = $two\n";
```

the result of this script exec:

```
one = test
two = test
```

The problem is that $1 is not reset after 1st successful regex match, as result second regex that is actually failed and should be empty, but instead it takes the value of $1 from the previous match. I found one strange workaround for reseting $1 = by adding odd regex after 1st regex:

```
"1" =~ /1/;
```

the result is now correct:

```
one = test
two =
```

The question is: is it the best practice for reseting $1?

Comment: **but instead it takes the value of $1 from the previous match**, How do you know this? Note that **$cont1** and **$conts** hold the same string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't reset `$1`.  Instead, always test to see if your regex matched before using any capture variables.

```
my $cont1 = 'item:test';
my $cont2 = 'item:test';

if ($cont1 =~ s/item:(.*)/$1/) {
    print "one = $1\n";
}

if ($cont2 =~ s/dtms:(.*)/$1/) {
    print "two = $1\n";
}
```

If you really want to initialize `$one` and `$two`, then use a `?:`

```
my $one = $cont1 =~ s/item:(.*)/$1/ ? $1 : '';
my $two = $cont2 =~ s/dtms:(.*)/$1/ ? $1 : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex capture variables are only reset on the next successful match. This way, Perl saves a lot of time by not affecting variables when matches fail. As such, only use those variables with a guard:

```
if( /abc/ ) {
    ...
    }
```

Here's an extended demonstration, with a special surprise at the end:

```
$_ = 'Hello Perl';
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# successful match
/(P)(erl)/;
print "First match\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# unsuccessful match
/(P)(ython)/;
print "Failed capture\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# successful match again
/(Pe)(r)(l)/;
print "Three captures\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# successful match, fewer captures
/(Perl)/;
print "One capture\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# successful match, no captures
/Perl/;
print "No captures\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# successful match, no pattern, special case
//;
print "No nothing\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";
```

The output:

```
$1:
$2:
$3:
$&:

First match
$1: P
$2: erl
$3:
$&: Perl

Failed capture
$1: P
$2: erl
$3:
$&: Perl

Three captures
$1: Pe
$2: r
$3: l
$&: Perl

One capture
$1: Perl
$2:
$3:
$&: Perl

No captures
$1:
$2:
$3:
$&: Perl

No nothing
$1:
$2:
$3:
$&:
```

You can see going from the first to second matches, the capture variables don't change. Since the second match (to get `Python`) fails, Perl doesn't bother to clear out the previous captures.

In the later matches, you can see that Perl clears out all the match variables, not just the ones that changed.

The last one is very interesting because it looks like it breaks the rules. The empty pattern, `//` looks like it should match every string, including the empty string. However, it looks like it doesn't clear out the variables.

But, it does something different than you think. The empty pattern `//` matches the last *successful* pattern again. That means there can be a failed match right before it and that's not the one it will try to repeat:

```
$_ = 'Hello Perl';

# successful match, fewer captures
/(P[a-z]+)/;
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# successful match, no captures
/Ruby/;
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# successful match, no pattern, special case
$_ = 'Hello Python';
//;
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";

# unsuccessful match, no pattern, special case
$_ = 'Hello Rust';
//;
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\n";
```

In the output, the first and second groups make sense in the same way that I just outlined. The first match is successful and sets some variables. The second match is not, and it does not clear out the variables:

```
$1: Perl
$2:
$3:
$&: Perl

$1: Perl
$2:
$3:
$&: Perl

$1: Python
$2:
$3:
$&: Python

$1: Python
$2:
$3:
$&: Python
```

The third match repeats the last successful pattern, `/(P[a-z]+)/`, but this time against a different string. The pattern also matches the current value of `$_` but it captures something else.

The fourth match repeats the last successful match, but this time on a string that won't match. Since that is unsuccessful, the capture variables are not cleared and hence carry over the values from the last successful match.

---

Now a bit of heterodoxy. You should always check the result of the match before using the capture variables:

```
if( /.../ ) {
    print "1: $1";
    }
```

You know that a successful match clears the match variables. But is there a match that will always be successful for every string but clear the match variables?

You don't want to match any character, though, because that will put something in `$&`. And, with there's a `$&`, the portion of the string that matched, there's also ``` $``, the portion of the string before that, and ``` $'`, the portion after that. If you don't care about those variables, this won't matter. The capture variables are cleared, but not every variable is cleared.

This demonstration is a bit different because I'm going to match successfully with captures (`/(P)(erl)/`) first, then try another match to see what happens. First, I'll just match `.`, which matches any character except the newline, but I'll add `(?s)` inside the regex to let `.` match a newline:

```
$_ = 'Hello Perl';

/(P)(erl)/;
/(?s)./;
print "No captures, but \$&\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\$`: $`\n\$': $'\n\n";
```

The `.` has to match as least one character, so it matches H. Even though there are no captures, the part of the string that matched the pattern show up in `$&`, and the part after that shows up in `$'`:

```
No captures, but $&
$1:
$2:
$3:
$&: H
$`:
$': ello Perl
```

Can I get rid of some of that? A look around is an assertion, which matches a condition rather than a character.

```
/(P)(erl)/;
/(?=.)/;
print "No captures, positive lookahead\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\$`: $`\n\$': $'\n\n";
```

The pattern matches at position zero, so the entire string ends up in `$'`:

```
No captures, positive lookahead
$1:
$2:
$3:
$&:
$`:
$': Hello Perl
```

Okay this seems to work. But there's one string that doesn't match here: the empty string. This is the sort of trap you get into when you know you have to be clever.

But, I don't have to be clever to match nothing. There are several other patterns that will do this. I could have matched a minimal pattern `.??` where the second `?` means the minimum version of zero or one (so zero), or `.{0}` to do the same thing. None of those match a character and all of them match at position zero. They can also match the empty string.

```
/(P)(erl)/;
'' =~ /.??/;
print "No captures, minimal optional\n";
print "\$1: $1\n\$2: $2\n\$3: $3\n\$&: $&\n\$`: $`\n\$': $'\n\n";
```

And, that match against the empty string now shows nothing in the any of the variables. That is, all these are false values:

```
No captures, minimal optional
$1:
$2:
$3:
$&:
$`:
$':
```

So, it looks like we have a way to have all the match variables have nothing in them, which is an approximation of clearing them.

But there's another thing to know. You can't use this in a subroutine, such as my `clear_re_vars`:

```
$_ = 'Hello Perl';

sub clear_re_vars { '' =~ /.??/; print "inside: $1\n" }

/(Perl)/;
print "first: $1\n";
clear_re_vars();
print "last: $1\n";
```

Here's the output:

```
first: Perl
inside:
last: Perl
```

Right after `/(Perl)/`, there's something in `$1`, and that's expected. I call them `clear_re_vars`, and in there the match clears `$1`, so there's no value in the second line of input. However, after the subroutine, the previous value of `$1` is back. That's because these special variables are dynamically scoped. Their changes, which you must do through a match or substitution operator, only last until the end of the scope. That way, you don't have to coordinate their use  throughout the program. In your scope, the match variables work as if nothing else outside of your scope  changed them.

So, you have to do all of that in the same scope:

```
$_ = 'Hello Perl';

/(Perl)/;
print "first: $1\n";
'' =~ /.??/;
print "last: $1\n";
```

But, this isn't what you want to be doing, even if there's a lot of discover about Perl just to get to this point.

Comment: <p>Hello Brian Foy;</p><p> When I run this code I get</p><p> No captures
$1: 
$2: 
$3: 
$&: Perl

No nothing
$1: 
$2: 
$3: 
$&: Perl</p><p>, //; does not seem to clear out $&.  What am I missing?</p>

Comment: I don't know what code you are running. Perhaps you should ask a new question and show the code that is not working as you expect.

Comment: Your illuminating code, only //; does not work for me the way it does for you. $& is not cleared.

Answer (score -2):

```
Used within a loop.
Reset $2 as undef. To get cleared use $ch =~ /^(a*)(b*)\d+$/;
$ch =~ /^(a)*(b)*\d+$/;\n
$ch++;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your code.